# Error handling promise save unique data in mongoDB (ValidationError)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, koa

I use Koa.js, mongodb and momgoose.js

I have a simple form in my client side, and I have some unique and required input.
When I submit my form, I try save this data in mongodb cross my Schema.

```
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstname: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });
const My = mongoose.model('My', mySchema);
```

function for save

```
function addDB(data) {
    return new Promise(() => {
        const bar = new My({ ...data });
        bar.save().then(() => console.log('success'));
    });
```

How I can catch error in db like this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: My validation failed: lastname: Path `lastname` is required.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the error with `catch` to avoid this error:

```
function addDB(data) {
    return new Promise(() => {
        const bar = new My({ ...data });
        bar.save().then(() => console.log('success')).catch(err=>console.log(err))
    });
```